# Why does x-terminal-emulator sometimes exit on launch and sometimes not?

Tags: java, gnome-terminal, process

From my Java program, I launch an x-terminal. The Java waits for the x-terminal command to start.  (It's a Datastore emulator for developers.)

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -e gcloud beta emulators datastore start");
proc.waitFor();
```

In some Ubuntu developer machines, `process.waitFor()` returns as soon as the command is launched. (The command continues to run in that terminal.)  This is the intended behavior.

In other Ubuntu developer machines, the `process.waitFor()` blocks permanently and never returns. (But the terminal command *has* launched, and if we kill the main Java process, that terminal command continues, as it should.)

What can cause this difference in behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator` is a symbolic link that can point to many different implementations of a terminal such as `gnome-terminal` or `konsole` among others. Each terminal may have it's own logic, but it's common for some programs to open a "master" process the first time then on subsequent opens simply tell the already running process to spawn another terminal or open another tab.

Comment: You're right! 

The machine where `process.waitFor()` did not exit had Terminator defined as the x-terminal-emulator, while other machines Gnome Terminal.

https://vitux.com/how-to-set-the-gnome-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu/